# Pod cannot pull image from private docker registry

Tags: kubernetes

I am having some real trouble getting my pods to pull images from a private docker registry that I have setup and am able to authenticate to (I can do docker login https://my.website.com/ and I get Login Succeeded without having to put in my username:password) (I am able to run `docker pull my.website.com:5000/human/forum` and see all the layers being downloaded.) .

I use https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_k8s#aliasing-eg-k8s_deploy where I specify the namespace to be `"default"`.

I made sure to put `"HTTPS://my.website.com:5000/V2/"` (in lowercase) in the auth section in the docker config file before I generated the `regcred` secret.

Notice that I specify the `imagePullSecrets` below:

```
# deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: angular-bazel-example-prod
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: angular-bazel-example-prod
    spec:
      containers:
       - name: angular-bazel-example
         image: human/forum:dev
         imagePullPolicy: Always
         ports:
         - containerPort: 8080
      imagePullSecrets:
       - name: regcred # Notice
```

I made sure to update my certificate authority certificates:

```
cp /etc/docker/certs.d/my.website.com\:5000/ca.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/my.website.registry.com/
sudo update-ca-certificates
```

I see `sudo curl --user testuser:testpassword --cacert /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/my.website.registry.com/ca.crt -X GET https://mywebsite.com:5000/v2/_catalog`

> `{"repositories":["human/forum"]}`

I see `sudo curl --user testuser:testpassword --cacert /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/mywebsite.registry.com/ca.crt -X GET https://mywebsite.com:5000/v2/human/forum/tags/list`

> `{"name":"a/repository","tags":["dev"]}`

There must be a way to troubleshoot this but I don't know how.

One thing I am curious about is

```
kubectl describe pod my-first-pod...
...
Volumes:
  default-token-mtz9g:
    Type:        Secret
```

Where can I find this volume? I can't `kubectl exec` into a container because none is running.. because the pod can't pull the image.

Do you have any ideas on how I could troubleshoot this?

Thank you!

Slackware

Answer (score 1):

Create a kubernetes secret to access the custom repository. One way is to provide the server, user and password manually. [Documentation link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#create-a-secret-by-providing-credentials-on-the-command-line).

```
kubectl create secret docker-registry $YOUR_REGISTRY_NAME --docker-server=https://$YOUR_SERVER_DNS/v2/ --docker-username=$YOUR_USER --docker-password=$YOUR_PASSWORD --docker-email=whatever@gmail.com --namespace=default
```

Then use it in your yaml

```
...
      imagePullSecrets:
       - name: $YOUR_REGISTRY_NAME
```

Regarding the default-token that you see mounted, it belongs to the service account that your pod uses to talk to the kubernetes api. You can find the service account by running `kubectl get sa` and `kubectl describe sa $DEFAULT_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ID`. Find the token by running `kubectl get secrets` and `kubectl describe secret $SECRET_ID`. To clarify this service account and token have nothing to do with the docker registry unless you specify it. To include the registry in the service account follow this guide [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-service-account/#add-imagepullsecrets-to-a-service-account)